# How to fetch data from mongodatabase?

Tags: android, database, mongodb, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have managed to connect a kotlin project made in jetpack compose to mongodatabase and can performe CRUD operations.

I am trying to fetch data stored in monogdatabase using jetpack compose and kotlin languages. For simplification, lets say I have 10 users. 2 of 10 users has the age of 18. My age on the app is 18. I want to fetch the data from mongodatabase and display those 2 users on a textfield saying "You matched with 2 users". If I were tp change my age from 18 -> 20. This in turn would match me with 3 users (lets say 3 users of 10 are age 20) etc. How can I achieve this feature?

How can this be done using mongoDb as a backend database and kotlin language in jetpack compose?

Appreciate any feedback and/or guidance! Obs - if more code is needed just let me know!

Fetch data from MongoDb:

```
@SuppressLint("AuthLeak")
fun getMongoClient(): MongoClient {
    return MongoClients.create(**My mongoDb string goes here**)
}

fun fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection: MongoCollection<Document>, age: Int): Int {
    val pipeline = listOf(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("age", age)),
        Aggregates.group(null, Accumulators.sum("count", 1))
    )

    val result = collection.aggregate(pipeline).firstOrNull()
    return result?.getInteger("count", 0) ?: 0
}


@Composable
fun MainMongoData() {
    var fetchedData by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var age by remember { mutableStateOf(18) } // Example: Default age set to 20

    Column {
// Age Input
        TextField(
            value = age.toString(),
            onValueChange = { age = it.toIntOrNull() ?: age },
            label = { Text("Enter Age") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )

// Display your fetched data
        Text("You matched with: $fetchedData people")
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow this feels like a matter of knowledge gap. You are literally asking a tutorial on how to do it. Did you even tried? If you tried what did you do? Whats blocking you to do what you want?. You just posted a code without explaining what is wrong with the code. You just provided us what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello Renz Carlo! Yes, I have created 3 projects but I run into the same problem. I got recommended lately to try and create a very simple but functional project to try and figure out why it does not work properly. Have done this but I still am stuck on the same problem, which in its core is: It does not fetch the data from mongo Db and it does not display it properly. If you want me to update the question with all the relevant information, I can do that. If you want me to push the project onto github to make it available and simple to test, I can do this as well! @RenzCarlo

Comment: Compose has nothing to do with db choice.

Comment: I understand but I am using mongodatabase as database but the code itself need to be written in kotlin language using declarativ UI with jetpack compose to be able to fetch the data. Or am I missing something/ am I misinterpreting something?@NikolaDespotoski